# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, while removing blur background

Tags: ios, swift, blur, subview

While adding blur effect to subview giving error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

For first time it working fine, if i try second time its giving above error.

outlets:

```
 @IBOutlet var mesgText_view: UIView!
 var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
```

**CODE:**

```
func OpenSubMesgView(_ sender : UIButton) {
   print(sender.tag)
   print("ARRAY VALUES FROM CELL",totlObservationArray.object(at: sender.tag))
   mesgText_view.alpha = 1
   var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
   blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
   blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
   blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
   view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
   blurEffectView.addSubview(mesgText_view)    
}   

 @IBAction func closeMesgview(_ sender:UIButton)    {
       mesgText_view.alpha = 0;
       self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
 }
```

Comment: On which line does the error happen?

Comment: blurEffectView.addSubview(mesgText_view)     here i am getting crash

Comment: We don't know much about `mesgText_view` - where it was created and was it initialized or not

Comment: where mesgText_view is uiview. i am dispalying one uiview on uiviewcontroller when button tapped.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
```

I'm going to guess that this and / or `mesgText_view` refers to an outlet, declared as weak like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
```

Weak variables are set to nil if nothing holds a strong reference to them. If you remove a weakly held view from its superview, it will be set to nil and the next time you try to reference it, your app will crash.

The first time your code runs it will be removing some weak outlet from its superview. Since it's a weak property, nothing else has a reference to it and it is made nil. The second time your code runs, it accesses the outlet which is now a nil implicitly unwrapped optional, causing your crash.

You could also make the outlet a strong reference by removing the `weak` keyword from the declaration. This would allow you to remove it from its superview without it being nilled out.

Comment: i did set  alpha =0 in one func and alpha=1 in another function

Comment: var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        blurEffectView.addSubview(mesgText_view)

Comment: i created blur effect

Comment: Oh sorry, the code in your question wasn't formatted very well, I didn't realise it was two functions :)

Comment: sorry for that.. straight question. how to add transparent or blur background when subview opened on view controller.

Comment: for example if alert view controller presents on view controller it shows background some transparent like that i am expecting

Comment: I've updated my answer. Pretty sure it's still about weak outlets, can you include the outlet descriptions in your question?

Comment: These are my outlet connections                                                                
    var blurEffectView=UIView()
    @IBOutlet weak var mesgText_view: UIView!

Comment: mesgTextView is nilled out when you assign a new visual effect view to blurEffectView, then when you try and access it, you crash. Make that outlet strong and you're fine.

Comment: i made mesgTextView outlet strong now its not crashing but alignment going to change on second tap onwards

Comment: You're just adding the view to a new superview, you may well have to add constraints or set a frame to get it to look right